# Problems logging into site with jsf login using Python Requests

Tags: python, post, authentication, python-requests

I know that this is similar to other Requests login problems, but for some reason nothing seems to be working with my code.
I'm attempting to login to https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/csologin/login.jsf
and I am using the following code

```
url = 'https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/csologin/login.jsf'
payload = {'login:loginName': uName, 'login:password': pWord}
search_payload = {'court_id': 'casdce', 'date_filed': '5/31/16'}
with requests.session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print p.text
```

and this just returns the text of the login page. What am I missing? Sorry if this seems like a duplicate question, I just have no idea what's going wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some post data:

```
data = {"login":"login",
       "login:loginName":uName,
       "login:password":pWord,
       "login:clientCode":"",
       "login:fbtnLogin":"",
       "javax.faces.ViewState":"stateless"}

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/csologin/login.jsf'

search_payload = {'court_id': 'casdce', 'date_filed': '5/31/16'}
with requests.session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print p.text
```

Adding  a *user-agent* is also generally a good idea. You can see the post data in developer tools:

[image]

You may or may not need to make a request to the site to store the cookies, if you do then just make an`s.get("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/csologin/login.jsf")` before you login

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed the problem. Now I'm getting an SSLError: certificate verify failed. When I set verify = False, it works, but obviously this is unsafe. I know nothing about SSL certification, how can I properly configure my certificates so as to avoid this Error?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I was trying it on my Linux machine and it wasn't working. Switched to Windows and no certificate errors

Comment: What was the full traceback on your linux box?